# Aborting a merge in git - Best practice

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge, abort

Say you are in a branch `topic`, you have been working for a while and want to merge in some commits from `master`.

You run `git merge` and there are a few conflicts. But you don't have time to resolve the merge conflicts now, and you want to return to the state that you were in before running `git merge`.

There are three ways of which I know to do this:

- `git merge --abort`
- `git reset --merge`
- `git reset --hard HEAD` ?

Is any one of the three acceptable? What is the difference between them in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git merge --abort` is preferable to `git reset --hard HEAD`, because (from [`git merge` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) it [will remove `.git/MERGE*` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21829654/6309) (like `MERGE_HEAD`).
`git reset --hard` will not, which means git will believe a merge is still in progress.

And `git reset --merge` is simply [what was used before `git merge --abort` was introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11647899/6309) (in git 1.7.4, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12577611/6309)).

Comment: @Vonc +1 You never cease to amaze me with your high quality version control answers since I started noticing your name when I was answering clearcase questions. Your high reputation is clearly well earned.

Comment: @hlovdal Thank you :) As you can see by the graph with my name on it, I have been working hard for that reputation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252757/6309